# Desktop app that always run in background

Tags: javascript, java

I was asked to build an app for windows that always runs in background when system starts. All the app does is update and insert to a database and it has no UI , i ve never came across such kind apps and i have pretty little knowledge about how to do it  .
Any sugesstions ??

Comment: A `windows service` perhaps?

Comment: The searchable word you're looking for is *service*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're essentially trying to build a windows service/ unix daemon.
I would recommend node-windows if you have NodeJS available to you, otherwise, there are plenty of ways to wrap your application as a windows service.

Here are some links to get you started.

[node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows),
[Java / Appache commons-daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/index.html)

Comment: Looks like this is what i am looking for and i am familiar with nodejs but can this service runs automatically after first installation after system restarts ??